# Postgresql difference between \dt+ and count rows

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, aws-dms

I'm running at now DMS (FULL LOAD, ONGOING REPLICATION) replication and I would like to check difference of rows between clusters A and B. and How B is delayed against A.
Database engine is postgresql 11(A) and postgresql14(B)

I run \dt+ on A:

```
                           List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Owner  | Persistence | Size  | Description
--------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+-------+-------------
 public | x | table | example | permanent   | 73 GB |
(1 row)
```

and on B:

```
                                   List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Owner  | Persistence | Access method | Size  | Description
--------+----------+-------+--------+-------------+---------------+-------+-------------
 public | x | table | example | permanent   | heap          | 14 GB |
```

I was surprised by the difference in size, which is huge, so I run the count on reader instance of this clusters:

reader A:

```
=> Select count(*) FROM X;
  count
----------
 47830564
(1 row)
```

reader B:

```
=> Select count(*) FROM X;
  count
----------
 47830564
(1 row)
```

And looks okay, but I don't understand why the difference in size is so big.

DMS is an aws service which is reinserting the rows in batches from A to B.

Comment: I don't know how the dms service works, but bloated tables return to their normal size in this type of migration.

Comment: DMS take 10k rows from source and insert them in target. After full load the replication slots will be created and native psql replication :) 
Thanks for answer! I will also make a python script which will compare counts between dbs, to double check that :)